# when i convert gui .py file to .exe file i am unable to see anything

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pyinstaller, windows-10-desktop

i am developing a gui app using Tkinter in python 2.7 but when converted it into .exe file using pyinstaller, i am unable to see it, command promp is comiing and disappearing in split second,
i did this with py2exe and it shwing error that cannot find ddls needed.[ddl error i have already msvcp100.dll visual studios 2013 but it is still showing same eroor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hQzf.png)

Comment: Show some code, otherwise I cannot help you

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 0):

Try sharing your code, I have some experience doing that but with the package cx_Freeze, some problems with TK files are related with envioroment variables, and you need to add some code to solve it.